# étale cohomology of valuation rings

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Let $S$ be the spectrum of a discrete valuation ring (we can assume complete or henselian if necessary). Is it true that the étale cohomology group $H_{et}^2(S,\mathbb{Z})$ is zero?If not in general under which conditions on the residue (resp. fraction) field of the ring defining $S$ is this true?

Comment: Perhaps you can ask this on mathoverflow.